# Account for / in location

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

In a .js file in my MVC 4 application I'm using ajax to call a function in my controller.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./serverFunction",
            data: JSON.stringify({ item: dataItem }),
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
```

The url is being set relative to the current location and I would like to keep it that way. The problem I have is that domain/app/folder/view and domain/app/folder/view/ are both valid locations and when the / is present at the end I need to go back another level in my url. I am currently able to handle this with the following change

```
 url: document.URL.substring(document.URL.length - 1, document.URL.length) == "/" ? "../serverFunction" : "./serverFunction"
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: we have always used @Url.Action for the url in the ajax call.  would something like that work for you?

Comment: Yeah I've done that as well, the reason I'm not in this case is because I would ideally like to keep this in a seperate javascript file and not in my view.

Comment: Even if it is in js file, there is workaround to use `Url.Action`. I will strongly recommend you to use that. If you want something like that sure I will help you

Comment: @Satpal Absolutely, I wasn't aware of a workaround. Can you post it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `URL` is in JavaScript file, there is workaround to use `Url.Action`. I will strongly recommend you to use that

Declare a JavaScript variable in view. In script section as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionUrl = '<%=Url.Action("actionname","controller")%>';
</script>
```

And use `actionUrl` in external file.